# Loop through json data and add items to DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to loop through json data  and add it to a dynamoDB table. It breaks on the docClient.put() Can anyone point me in the right direction or explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
async function SaveJson(json) {
    let i;
    let promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        promises.push(doSomethingAsync(json[i]));
    }
}

function doSomethingAsync(record) {

    let params = {
        TableName: 'table-name',
        Item: {
            'Number': record.Number,
            'Unit': record.Unit
    }
};

console.log('Adding a new item...');


let putItem = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    docClient.put(params, function (err, data) { //breaks here
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
            rej(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Success', data);
            res('data inserted sucessfully');
        }
    });
  });
  return putItem;
 }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on the errors you are receiving?

Comment: I am not receiving an error. That's the problem. When I step through the code it gets to  docClient.put(params, function (err, data) { //breaks here. It doesn't throw an error. I wish it did.

Comment: @MountainBiker put it inside a try/catch block

Comment: It's already in a try catch block, I just didn't include it for brevity. No error there either. It doesn't even enter the catch. It hits this line docClient.put(params, function (err, data) { and then stops. It loops through each item successfully. The params are not even being passed to dynamodb for an item. I think it's a promises issue and it is not waiting for each to finish before it starts the next iteration...